# Derived Class How to inject ？

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

ASP.Net Core Web API

Does the parent class have no empty constructor 
derived class Autofac injection ?

If the injection class is added after the parameter, it cannot be used

```
  public class A    
  {    
        public A(string e1,string e2){}  
  }

  public class B:A
  {    
        private readonly IProductService _productService;     
        public B(IProductService productService):base(string e1,string e2)
        {
              _productService = productService
        }
        public void test()
        {
              _productService.AddProduct("");
        }
  }
```

AutoFac has no problem configuring

_productService exception occurred

Comment: Hi Joey, can you complete your question and say to us what exception occurred  ?!

Comment: You have to pass something into the base constructor.  `public B(IProductService productService):base(string e1,string e2)` is incorrect.  None of this code will compile.  `A` cannot have two constructors that vary only by the names of their parameters.

Comment: How do I inject IProductService into this derived class?

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like this:

```
public B(IProductService productService, string e1,string e2):base(e1,e2)
{
    _productService = productService
}
```

And then configure Autofac like this for this class registration:

```
builder.Register(c => new B(c.Resolve<IProductService>(), "e1_val","e2_val"));
```

If the `B` class will implement an interface at some point you can use it like this also:

```
builder.RegisterType<B>().As<IB>()
       .WithParameter("e1", "e1value")
       .WithParameter("e2", "e2value");
```

Keep in mind that you have a lot of flexibility with Autofac, please check their documentation at: [Autofac Parameters Register](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html) for even more information.